# What do you call a term someone savoured and defiled a bit of food and left it

Tags: word-request, verbs, adjectives, nouns

We Indian don't eat food that was eaten by someone else. For example:

- If someone has taken or tasted a little pizza and left it then we do not eat it.  We call it जूठा .  I am looking for the word in English that the food was eaten a bit and left

Comment: This concept is culturally specific. I'd guess an Indian English speaker will have a specific word for it (maybe just a transliteration of the original), but Americans or British people don't.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if English has a word specifically for that, but the first word that came to my mind is *touched*:

> I wouldn't eat the omelet. It's been touched.

In this context, word *touched* doesn't mean the omelet was necessarily touched by the fingers or a hand; it is speaking more about being touched by utensils during the act of eating. Or, as the dictionary says:

> **[touch](http://wordnik.com/words/touch)** (*trans. v*.) To eat or drink; taste : *She didn't touch her food*.

In conversation, the word might be used like this:

> **Stan**: Ew, Dan, why are you eating her hamburger?
>   **Dan**: Why not? She didn't touch it.

You can also use *untouched* as an antonym:

> Do you want to eat my fish? It's untouched.

Answer (score 2):

That could be said in several ways in English.  Leftovers is the term for food made in abundance and eaten at a later time.  Usage:  "There was too much pizza so I'll have to eat the leftovers tomorrow."

A word with a slightly negative connotation is the term scraps, which means the undesirable part of food left uneaten or also the part of the food defiled by the first person who ate from it.  Scraps may be something you would give your dog after you've eaten all you wish from your plate.  Usage:  "He picked off all the pepperoni and cheese from the pizza and left me with the scraps."

Comment: To add to this, if the context doesn't make it clear what scraps you're referring to, you can use the term *table scraps* to specify you're talking about leftover food.

Comment: Leftovers are something that are certainly for eating, whereas the Hindi word carries the opposite implication: food to be wasted.